# jQuery hide buttons if they don't contain text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some buttons with dynamically generated text inside. However sometimes there will be no text generated so I want to hide the button with jQuery. However I cannot seem to get it to work.

Below is my code:

```
$('.inner:empty').parent().remove();

<button><span class="inner">{{dynamic1}}</span></button>
<button><span class="inner">{{dynamic2}}</span></button>
<button><span class="inner">{{dynamic3}}</span></button>
<button><span class="inner">{{dynamic4}}</span></button>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are forgetting to wrap your selector in string quotes...

Comment: oops they actually were wrapped and it still doesn't work.

Comment: it does work wrapped, what version of jquery are you using? https://jsfiddle.net/onomLp75/

Comment: 1. any errors you get in your js console? and 2. if not, what does the selector return?

Comment: version 1.11.2, also using AngularJS, so maybe it's something to do with Angular.

Comment: No console errors.

Selector returns: [prevObject: m.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: ".inner:empty", jquery: "1.11.2", constructor: function…]context: documentlength: 0prevObject: m.fn.init[1]selector: ".inner:empty"__proto__: m[0]

Comment: I tried with static text and it worked. It is something to do with the dynamic text. I checked for it returning whitespace but my inspector shows:

    <span class="inner"></span>

so it should work?

Answer (score 0):

This satifies your requirements. You just need to use quotes around your selector and call hide instead of remove. Works with all versions of jQuery available on the Google jQuery CDN (1.2.3 - 2.1.1)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // You can replace 'hide' with 'remove' if you want it purged from the DOM.
  $('.inner:empty').parent().hide(); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button><span class="inner">Hello</span></button>
<button><span class="inner"></span></button>
<button><span class="inner">World</span></button>
<button><span class="inner"></span></button>
```

Comment: Why `hide()` and not `remove()`?

Comment: OP wanted "to hide the button". I am going by what is stated in the question.